# Ruby: Can't save document with Libxml-ruby

Tags: ruby, libxml-ruby

From the libxml-ruby API docs (http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/index.html), under LibXML::XML::Document, I tried the following:

```
filename = 'something.xml'
stats_doc = XML::Document.new()
stats_doc.root = XML::Node.new('root_node')
stats_doc.root << XML::Node.new('elem1')
stats_doc.save(filename, :indent => true, :encoding => 'utf-8')
```

... which resulted in this error:

```
parse_stats.rb:26:in `save': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

(where the last line in the block above was line 26).

I tried changing the file name to an integer, which gave me this:

```
parse_stats.rb:26:in `save': wrong argument type Fixnum (expected String) (TypeError)
```

So I gathered that I need to use a string, but strings don't seem to work.  Since I seem to be unable to find any examples of libxml-ruby in action off Google, I'm at a loss.  Any help would be very appreciated, or links to any online example where I can see how libxml-ruby is used for creating XML documents.

libxml-ruby 1.1.3
rubygems 1.3.1
ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the problem is with encoding. Try [XML::Encoding::UTF_8](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/LibXML/XML/Encoding.html) instead of "utf-8".

Comment: Probably outdated documentation, change 0.9.6 here mentions breaking the old code: http://libxml.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/CHANGES.html

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'libxml'

filename = 'something.xml'
stats_doc = LibXML::XML::Document.new()
stats_doc.root = LibXML::XML::Node.new('root_node')
stats_doc.root << LibXML::XML::Node.new('elem1')
stats_doc.save(filename, :indent => true, :encoding => LibXML::XML::Encoding::UTF_8)
```